# Redux-observable Testing and losing my Marbles

Tags: testing, redux, rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs-marbles

I want to test this observable but I get NOTHING back from it:

```
const fetchUsersApi = (action$: any) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_USERS),
    mergeMap(() => from(
        API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.LIST_ALL_USERS)),
    ).pipe(
        map((res: any) => fetchUsersSuccess(
            // TODO - standardise this to 'items' so fetchApi can be used
            pathOr(null, ['data', 'listAllUsers', 'users'], res),
        )),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
            const processedError = processAppSyncErrorMessage(error);
            console.log('Error', processedError);
            return of(addError(processedError), fetchUsersError(processedError));
        }),
    )),
);
```

The test is as follows:

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
import { ActionsObservable } from 'redux-observable';
import { fetchUsersSuccess, fetchUsers } from '../actions';

import fetchUsersEpic from './fetchUsersApi';

jest.mock('aws-amplify');

const testScheduler = new TestScheduler(
    (actual, expected) => expect(actual).toStrictEqual(expected),
);

describe('fetchUsersEpic', () => {
    it('should fetch the users', () => {
        const mockFetchedUsers = [
            { id: 'fakeUser1' },
        ];
        (API.graphql as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
            data: { listAllUsers: { users: mockFetchedUsers } },
        }));
        testScheduler.run((helpers) => {
            const {
                hot,
                cold,
                expectObservable,
                flush,
            } = helpers;
            const action$ = cold('-a', {
                a: fetchUsers(),
            });

            const reduxObservableaAction = ActionsObservable.from(action$);

            const actual = fetchUsersEpic(reduxObservableaAction);
            const expectedMarbles = '-b';
            const expectedValues = { b: fetchUsersSuccess(mockFetchedUsers) };

            expectObservable(actual).toBe(expectedMarbles, expectedValues);
            flush();
        });
    });
});
```

The result I get back is:

● fetchUsersEpic › should fetch the users

expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected  - 18

- Received  +  1

Obviously I'm missing something here, I was thinking the value returned should be the fetchUsersSuccess() callback with some data but instead we get an empty array. Would be great to get some ideas.

Comment: Try mocking `API.graphql` to return an observable rather than a promise. Promise callbacks are executed asynchronously

Comment: I just decided to black box at the store level and dispatch events and wrote a middleware that has a jest.fn() passed in to receive any actions on the store. Worked fine even though it's hardly a unit test!

Comment: I'm glad you got something working. Bear in mind in future that any time you introduce Promises you'll need to wait for the result, not just with marble tests!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to ignore the testing solutions provided and do a test of the whole store. It works better and if we decide to bin redux-observable we can still keep the tests.

```
import {
    applyMiddleware, createStore, Action,
} from 'redux';

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics, Epic } from 'redux-observable';

import rootReducer from '../../store/reducers';

/**
 * makeActionListMiddleware is a function to allow us to pass a jest mock
 * function to the store to pick up on any actions that are called on it
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const makeActionMiddleware = (jestMockFunction: jest.Mock) => (store: object) => (next: any) => (action: Action<any>) => {
    jestMockFunction(action);
    // continue to the next action
    return next(action);
};

// creates a fake version of the store with selected epics combined and a jest
// function middleware that received all store events.
const createEpicTester = (
    epics: Epic[],
    reducers = rootReducer,
    initialState = {},
) => {
    const storeActionJestCallback = jest.fn();
    const jestActionMiddleware = makeActionMiddleware(storeActionJestCallback);
    const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({});
    const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
    const store = createStore(reducers, initialState, composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware, jestActionMiddleware),
    ));
    epicMiddleware.run(combineEpics(...epics));
    return { store, dispatch: store.dispatch, storeActionJestCallback };
};

export default createEpicTester;
```

*Usage*

```
const { dispatch, storeActionJestCallback } = createEpicTester([epic]);
dispatch({ type: "someEvent" });
expect(storeActionJestCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: "someEvent" });
```

You can now expect further events that your epic applied to the store.